# cross domain ajax call with jquery failing parse

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, cross-domain

I'm attempting to make a cross domain script call to get some JSON data from a remote server, I can see the request being made and the data being returned successfully using Fiddler, but the calls is failing because it is failing to parse the JSON - the JSON is valid...

Is there anything wrong with the following jquery ajax call?

jquery version = 1.7.1

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'http://fooed.cloudapp.net/users?callback=?',
            crossDomain: true,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                alert('success');
            },
            error: function(data) {
                alert('error');
            },
            complete: function(xhr, data) {
                if (xhr.status == 0)
                    alert('fail');
                else
                    alert('success');
            }
        });
```

Example JSON:

```
[{ "ContentPreferences":[],
   "Email":"mark.jones@somedomain.com",
   "FirstName":"Mark",
   "Id":"aa2f1944-e739-4329-9546-a21f52c02448",
   "KnownAs":"Mark",
   "LastName":"Jones",
   "TimeStamp":"\/Date(1323804151906)\/"
}]
```

Comment: What do you get if you navigate directly to `http://fooed.cloudapp.net/users?callback=foo` can you paste it into your question? I can almost bet the `json` is valid `json` but not valid `jsonp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your json is not valid jsonp. It should look like this instead:

```
foo([{ "ContentPreferences":[],
     "Email":"mark.jones@somedomain.com",
    "FirstName":"Mark",
    "Id":"aa2f1944-e739-4329-9546-a21f52c02448",
    "KnownAs":"Mark",
    "LastName":"Jones",
    "TimeStamp":"\/Date(1323804151906)\/"
 }])
```

That means that the api doesn't support jsonp or requires a different param than `callback=?`

Comment: Correct. If you can't get it to return jsonp, you would have to use either a server-side proxy or an online proxy such as YQL.

Comment: and will YQL allow me to do POST, PUT & DELETE as well as GET?

Comment: no, it is not possible to do anything other than GET cross-domain using AJAX, other than maybe coors? (which i don't know very much about)